# Read google user detail with azure token

Tags: c#, azure, google-api, azure-mobile-services, access-token

I'm using Azure mobile services after login with google account i am getting azure access token, this token i am using to send request to service end. here is my code that return the access token and Sid,

```
MobileServiceClient client =new MobileServiceClient();

> var user = await client.LoginAsync(Forms.Context, provider);
```

But now i have azure access token but i need the google access token to get user detail. So please help me how i can get the google user detail with Azure access token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MoblieServiceClient providing only two fields in response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591054/moblieserviceclient-providing-only-two-fields-in-response)

Answer (score 0):

Send a request to your endpoint `/.auth/me` with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to the token.  This will return a JSON blob that contains the provider token.