# MoblieServiceClient providing only two fields in response

Tags: google-api, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using MobileServiceClient for authentication, my provider is Microsoft and Google. After success login in response I am getting auth Token and Sid. But I want more detail. I am using this service for Xamarin forms. Is there any way to get more detail of login user like email, username, verified_email, family_name etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Send a request to the `/.auth/me` endpoint with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header set to the ZUMO token.  You will get back a JSON blob that contains all the claims plus the identity provider token.  You can use these to get the information you need if it is available.

Comment: You mean to say i have to hit the end point like this. "http://{ServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me" with X-ZUMO-AUTH header, after hit this end point like this, this message is coming "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: You need to use https

Comment: @GurpreetSingh You also need to turn on each of these claims in App Service Authentication in the Azure portal when you set up the Google provider.